# 301 Redirect not working htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have changed my photo gallery to a subdomain of my web hosting account.

Since google is still referencing the old links to my pictures, I want to do a 301 redirect with htaccess. In the 301 redirect I think the best way is to
search incoming URL for specific string in old link and if found then just append photos to link as subdomain.

eg
incoming URL - `http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/photography-...y/12345_crABCD`

check incoming URL's for string "photography-gallery"
if found then 301 rewrite URL by appending subdomain photos to URL

```
photos.MYDOMAIN.com/photography-gallery/12345_crABCD
```

I also tried this redirectin htaccess to just go to my domain if string found and it did not do anything

```
redirect 301 /photography-gallery/ http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/
```

Can someone help with writing the expression for this htaccess redirect or rewrite? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into [.htaccess Rewrites](http://codular.com/htaccess-introduction), which will allow you to conditionally redirect.

You will want to check if the url matches `/photography-gallery/` at any point, and then redirect that off to the subdomain.

```
RewriteRule ^\/photography-gallery\/([0-9a-z_A-Z]+)\/?$ http://photos.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above should do it for you. Also, take a look at using Google Webmaster Tools for ensuring that paths are redirecting correctly etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it that a try. I also tried another way for redirect and this seems to work too
RedirectMatch 301 ^/photography-gallery/(.*)$ http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/

Comment: wow that is great link on to know. its like learning new language and that link is like rosetta stone. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the same URL to another domain, you can use this simple [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photography-gallery/.*$ http://photos.mydomain.com/$0 [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Comment: Ok I tried the 2 codes given and none of them work.  I then made some minor tweaks and tried it again and it still did not redirect correctly. Could the special characters #,! in the original URL be messing up the redirect?

This is code I tweaked and used

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/Photo-Gallery/(.+)$ http://photos.MYDMAIN.com/$1 [R=301,L]

I tried this original URL to my gallery 
http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/XYZ/ABC/28346798_nGctqv#!i=2399742179&k=MbKVDWq
and it RETURNS this value in URL and went to my homepage instead of correct link
http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/#!i=2399742179&k=MbKVDWq

Comment: @user2280480 Please copy the rule as I wrote it. There is *no* leading slash in the rule pattern. And please don't use `R=301`, unless the rules work as they should.